# Laravel relationships cause errors when reaching respective properties in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

In the Laravel controller I have something like:

```
$entry = Entry::with('studio','user','user.operator','type', 'chef')
    ->find($entryId);

// return entry with database fields and relationships
```

**Now in Vue(works through Vuex and Axios):**

1. If I try get properties of Entry element, that's work perfectly fine:

   ```
   {{!entry.occurred_at ? '-' : entry.occurred_at}}

   // output
   // 2017-09-03 16:45:46
   ```
2. If I try to get something out out Entry class relationship(which I received thanks to with() method) one level deep its fine too:

   ```
   {{!entry.user ? '-' : entry.user}}

   //output
   // { "id": 50, "username": "mihails.vankins", "change_password": 0, "logged_in_at": "2019-09-18 14:57:36", "deleted_at": false, "created_at": "2018-06-04 16:59:41", "updated_at": "2019-09-18 21:01:04" }
   ```

3.But if I try to get more then one level deep into relationships like so:

```
 {{!entry.user.username ? '-' : entry.user.username }}
```

I receive correct output, but in my console I get an errors like:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.entry.user is undefined"
TypeError: "_vm.entry.user is undefined"
```

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check like this:

```
 {{(entry.user && entry.user.username) ?entry.user.username :'-'  }}
```

if there was more object levels for example:

```
{{ (entry.user && entry.user.fullname && entry.user.fullname.first && ...)   }}
```